# Запрос к БД в MySQL, ошибка условия

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть запрос к MySQL

```
 SELECT *,profiuser.idcity as idcity1  FROM profiuser  
    LEFT JOIN profi ON profiuser.idprofi=profi.idprofi
    LEFT JOIN city ON profiuser.idcity=city.idcity
    LEFT JOIN users ON profiuser.idu=users.idu
```

так работает.
Если добавляю условие отбора WHERE idcity1=12

```
SELECT *,profiuser.idcity as idcity1  FROM profiuser  
LEFT JOIN profi ON profiuser.idprofi=profi.idprofi
LEFT JOIN city ON profiuser.idcity=city.idcity
LEFT JOIN users ON profiuser.idu=users.idu 
WHERE idcity1=12
```

ругается на #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'idcity1' в 'where clause'
почему не определяется столбец не пойму

Как мне отобрать все данные с idcity1=12 ?

Comment: where выполняется до select и то что написано в нем еще не известно. ссылайтесь на сам столбец profiuser.idcity

Comment: благодарю, все получилось